# Get Calendar Week Difference Between Local Dates

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm having trouble finding a post where the solution is something else besides

> Get day difference and divide by 7

I'm looking to get the difference in calendar weeks between two dates, where the weeks start on Mondays.

For instance, the number of weeks between Nov 4th, 2019 and Nov 10th, 2019 should be 0.

However, the number of weeks between Nov 10th, 2019 and Nov 11th, 2019 should be 1.

The solution should also account for dates in different years. Any solutions that use `LocalDate`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ChronoUnit`s have [a `between` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-) which returns the number of complete units between a start and end date/time. To count weeks Monday to Sunday, you could "round down" your dates to the previous Monday. In your case it could look like this:

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(2019, 11, 10);
LocalDate end = LocalDate.of(2019, 11, 11);

LocalDate mondayStart = start.with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
LocalDate mondayEnd = end.with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));

System.out.println(ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between(mondayStart, mondayEnd));
```

Comment: This seems like a variation of the "divide by 7" advice, with a `floor` added to it. It still doesn't pass my second test of Nov 10 - Nov 11 returning a week difference of 1. Even if I changed my requirements to use Sunday as the start day and use Nov 9 - Nov 10, 0 is returned.

Comment: @JCamacho I misunderstood your question - see my edit.

Comment: Nice! `TemporalAdjusters` have been so helpful for my calendar app! Nice thinking to force dates to the week start, that way using the `between` method or a custom "divide by 7" method works no problem! Even better, this will work regardless of what I choose to be the start of the week.

Answer (score 3):

I would start with a known Monday and calculate the week number counting from then.
1st Jan 1962 was a Monday (other Mondays are available).

```
LocalDate knownMonday = LocalDate.of(1962,1,1);
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(2019, 11, 10);
LocalDate end   = LocalDate.of(2019, 11, 11);
long sWeek = (long)Math.floor(knownMonday.until(start,ChronoUnit.DAYS)/7.0);
long lWeek = (long)Math.floor(knownMonday.until(end  ,ChronoUnit.DAYS)/7.0);
System.out.println(lWeek-sWeek);
```

Comment: Thank you - I had to "Get day difference and divide by 7" just to be awkward.

Comment: Pesky Java rounds to zero instead of rounding down. Editing answer to use Math.floor() :(

Comment: Cool.  I believe this works correctly now.  Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Use GregorianCalendar . It has methods for computing differences in terms of weeks.

Comment: Pretty sure it doesn't have such methods.  And it's been obsolete for about six years.